# What is the intuition behind the logic of converting directed graph into undirected graph?

Tags: graphs

I was looking  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369714/transform-a-simple-directed-graph-to-a-simple-undirected-graph , but i couldnt really understand the thought process behind this. Please help me.

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with? There's a couple of answers there that do slightly different things.

Comment: What specifically are you confused about?  What parts do you understand, and what's the first part that you don't understand?  The more you can share with us about your thought process and what you are unsure about, the more likely that we can help you.

Comment: How can one bring the notion of directedness in an un-directed graph? How should I start thinking about it?

Comment: @LukeMathieson, Yes both the answers talk about adding vertices and edges, What is the intuition behind adding those edges and vertices?

Comment: The question is not really well-defined. One answer shows the reduction from directed graph isomorphism to undirected graph isomorphism, and the rest seem completely arbitrary. It's like asking how to convert a signed number into an unsigned number.